# How to change the size of image by giving input in textbox in C# windows form?

Tags: c#

I have a image in Windows form and two text boxes. I want that when I enter the values in those textboxes and press enter, it should affect the image: height and width of the image should be changed to textbox values.

```
private void buttonZ1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
   pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
   pb.Image = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\rectangle.png");
   Point p = new Point(250 + i, 60 * i);

   pb.Location = p;
   this.Controls.Add(pb);
   i++;
   textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(pb.Height);
   textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(pb.Width);
   textBox3.Text = pb.Location.X.ToString();
   textBox4.Text = pb.Location.Y.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Height = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    pb.Width = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
}
```

Comment: In what way is this not working?  Note that you're creating a `PictureBox` and setting its `Height` and `Width`, but then you're not *doing anything* with it.  You never display it.

Comment: You need to reuse the same `PictureBox` instance everywhere in your form. Otherwise you just keep adding new ones. Make `pb` an instance variable and avoid recreating it.

Comment: What should be done next please help as i am new in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you do this:

```
new PictureBox()
```

You create a *new* `PictureBox`, completely unrelated to any other `PictureBox` that already exists.  So in your `button1_Click` method, each time you click that button you create a new `PictureBox`.  But then you never display that `PictureBox`, it just exists only in memory (until the method ends, then it's gone).

It sounds like you want to set the values of the `PictureBox` you created in `buttonZ1_Click`.  If that's the case, make it a class-level variable on the form.  Something like this:

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

private void buttonZ1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pb.Image = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\rectangle.png");
    // etc.

    // The code here doesn't change, you just remove the first "new PictureBox()" line
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pb.Height = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    pb.Width = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
}
```

The only difference between this code and yours is that the instance of the `PictureBox` is declared and created at the class level, instead of repeatedly in each method.  So each method will be using the same instance of the `PictureBox`.  (Note how the command `new PictureBox()` is now only ever invoked *once*, so only one instance is created.)

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you make a new instance each every time for your `PictureBox` Control, you should give a name for your PictureBox control in the winforms Designer, then do something like this in the code behind:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PictureBoxName.Width = TxtBox1.Text;
        PictureBoxName.Height = TxtBox2.Text;



    }
```

it will make sure you using the same instance every time you click the Button.

Please ensure that you set integer values on the TextBox control, you may make some validation for it.

Comment: What to do for finding location on button_1 click